# Is it possible to attach a promise to a click event

Tags: javascript, angularjs, oauth-2.0

I could not find any relevant questions for this on stackoverflow or google (newbie here). I have an angularJS application which is using oauth2 (using dropbox core API ) to login the user. The application shows the 'redirect' to dropbox url in a 'click here' message. The user clicks, a new browser window opens with the redirection address, the user signs in to dropbox. Dropbox calls my express server callback function, my express server sends success message to the client. 
However, the problem is that the 'success' message from the express server is received by the browser window instead of the angularJS client application. How can i attach a promise to the click event or listen to this click event and take actions in the client application based on the response from the server to the click event. What is the correct way to handle this scenario?
Any insight is greatly appreciated! 
Thanks!

Comment: Doubt you can do what you want to do since the promise needs to be with the call that makes the oauth request.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I tried to do this redirection in the code as well but then I get a CORS error in the browser's console. When i click on that link, the redirection works but the issue is the same, the server response is received by the browser window!

Comment: use this [`window.opener`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/opener) to call/tell parent/main window that outh is success or fail.

Comment: What is your real issue here that you are trying to solve? How are you doing the oauth call?

Comment: Thanks @Jag, I will try this.

Comment: Oauth call is done like this: 1. user clicks on redirect link. 2. gets authenticated from dropbox. 3. dropbox calls my server callback function. server callback function sends success to the client application after doing some internal book keeping.4. the client application should receive the response and take some actions. However, in this case, the client is not able to get the response form oauth.